# Aligning a jQuery UI dialog in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to open a modal in a div that is on the parent page. Both pages are on the same domain. I had to add the following to allow it to work. But my modal position is affected by the iframe size and location.

Code added to parent: `document.domain="domain.com"`

Code added to iframe script: `document.domain="domain.com";`

I still can't get my modal to a relative position. I want it to be centered on the browser window. But all it does is set it relative to the parent document and linked to the iframe size and position. I used the following code in the dialog call:

`position: {my:'center',at:'center',of: parent.window},`

If you open the iframe page on it's own it works fine. But when called from within an iframe, it will not align correctly, even though the div for the modal is on the parent page.

Here is a sample page with an iframe of 1600 wide (100%). When you click on an image the modal opens and aligns close to the center of the document (http://scott.vidsnippets.com/). But when I reduce the iframe width to 600, the modal location moves to the left side (http://scott.vidsnippets.com/broken-link-test/).

Scott.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with 
JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M). I suggest Plunker, because you can actually setup multiple pages with working iframes.